# Vim: Paste seems to be acting weird. Carrying out the keyboard shortcuts of characters that are copy pasted

Tags: vim

My vim seems to be acting weird today.
When I try to copy paste it is carrying out the vim keyboard shortcuts related to the characters I have copied and pasted. 
 e.g. If i copy and paste two letter ks they will not paste but the cursor will jump up two lines. 
 I think it has something to do with SHIFT+CTRL+V taking me out of insert mode and into normal mode. 
Then paste is putting the kk as input into normal mode.
How do I get back to the correct copy paste functionality/ stop making shift+ctrl+v exit insert mode? 
Thanks!

Comment: `:set paste` should help you or set it in vimrc

Comment: `:set paste` doesn't work, it is still just carrying out the keyboard shortcuts instead of pasting the characters.

Comment: Does this also happen when you launch vanilla vim without your vimrc (using `vim -u NONE`)?

Comment: Yes it does. I also don't have a vimrc. I have deleted vim and started from scratch, it's still happening.

This is happening on a computing cluster vim, my local vim is fine.

Answer (score 0):

My cluster terminal went into bracketed paste mode while in vim somehow.
Typing `reset` into the terminal outside of vim fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).